# How can I use other fonts in Glut - Fungen - Haskell

Tags: haskell, glut, bitmap-fonts

I'm using the [Fungen](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/FunGEn) framework for Haskell and there is a function that uses BitmapFonts. The thing is, that the only BitmapFonts I can use are the ones that come with GLUT, here is the data:

data BitmapFont
= Fixed8By13
| Fixed9By15
| TimesRoman10
| TimesRoman24
| Helvetica10
| Helvetica12
| Helvetica18

These fonts are very small for my application, and I want to use another BitmapFont, not just these, or make one of these bigger. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the source of [putGameText](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/FunGEn/0.3/doc/html/src/Graphics-UI-Fungen-Text.html#putGameText):

```
putGameText :: [Text] -> IO ()
putGameText [] = return ()
putGameText ((text,font,(x,y),r,g,b):ts) = do
    loadIdentity
    color (Color3 r g b)
    rasterPos (Vertex2 x y)
    renderString font text
    putGameText ts
```

As I understand it, FunGEn's Text type constrains font to a fixed-size [BitMapFont](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/FunGEn/0.3/doc/html/Graphics-UI-Fungen-Text.html):

```
type Text = (String, BitmapFont, (GLdouble, GLdouble), GLclampf, GLclampf, GLclampf)
```

but renderString can also take a [StrokeFont](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/GLUT/latest/doc/html/Graphics-UI-GLUT-Fonts.html#t%3aStrokeFont), which is even more limited in font family but responds to standard OpenGL [scaling/transformation/rotation](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/OpenGL/latest/doc/html/Graphics-Rendering-OpenGL-GL-CoordTrans.html#t%3aMatrixComponent).

So, a good start might be to make myPutGameText that accepts a StrokeFont-capable MyText and does a scaling transform before rendering. Here's some pseudo-code which I hope someone will correct:

```
type MyText = (String, StrokeFont, (GLdouble, GLdouble), GLclampf, GLclampf, GLclampf)

myPutGameText :: [MyText] -> (GLDouble,GLDouble,GLDouble) -> IO ()
myPutGameText [] _ = return ()
myPutGameText ((text,font,(x,y),r,g,b):ts) (sx,sy,sz) = do
    loadIdentity
    preservingMatrix $ do
      scale sx sy sz
      color (Color3 r g b)
      rasterPos (Vertex2 x y)
      renderString font text
      putGameText ts
```

For richer font rendering, the answer is probably to integrate something like [FTGL](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/FTGL).

Comment: I Had replaced the BitmapFont for a StrokeFont changing FunGen's code, but the strokeFonts were too big!. But I didn't know I could change strokeFonts size, I'm going to try it and tell you what happened. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: I changed the strokeFont size but after doing it, the text just appeared at the bottom of the screen, and I couldn't change its position. that just happens after changing its size. I decided to use a fixed bitmapFont in my game, because I don't have time to waste with fonts. Thanks for the answer anyway